# Fx.Reveal event when done (complete)

Tags: mootools

hi sorry completely new to mootools used to jquery, have a container (saved to variable itemContent) which reveals,

after this a function galleryScroll is call which scrolls the element to the container saved to var itemScroll,

want to make sure itemContent is revealed before scroll function is called whats the best way to do this?

thanks

```
itemContent.reveal({
                'height' : '100%',
                duration: 1600, 
            }).addClass('open-content');

            // should this fire this in  a callback function so it fires once the container is revealed



            galleryScroll.toElement(itemScroll);
```

Answer (score 0):

Fx.Reveal extends Fx and as such, inherits all of it's events.

try via the element setter:

```
itemCount.set('reveal', {
    onComplete: function(){
        galleryScroll.toElement(this.element);
    }
}.reveal({... });
```

you can also get the reveal instance:

```
var fxReveal = itemCount.get('reveal');
```

this will return the instance and you can set whatever you like to it like usual.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable chaining with the `link` option.

```
itemContent.reveal({
    'height': '100%',
    duration: 1600,
    link: 'chain'
}).addClass('open-content');
```

This example will hide, reveal and then alert. Please note that I need to get the `reveal` instance as the standard Element in mootools does not implement the Chain class.

```
document.id('first').set('reveal', {
    duration: 'long',
    transition: 'bounce:out',
    link: 'chain'
}).dissolve().reveal().get('reveal').chain(function(){alert('message');});
```

To see it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/LKSN8/1/